# How to remove error class from the element which validate?

Tags: php, jquery

I have validation in my form and when validation occure all textbox border-color change to red,but when the field success the validation how to remove this error class from field?

my css for error class is :.error {border:2px solid #f00 !important;}
and in jquery what we have to right to remove this red border from textboxes?

success: function() {
}
what we have to pass here??

Comment: try `$('.error').removeClass('error');`

Comment: Thanx for suggestion but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("Your jQuery selector").removeClass("error");
```

See jquery [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: @ButaniVijay: I apply this but when i click on submit button it removes class form all textbox including which is not filled,i want to remove from only those trextbox which goes filled

Comment: so you can remove using its id as i describe in my answer.

Comment: Yes you can use its id and remove its class for sure. I have tried it.

Comment: @YaminLawar are you using class as a selector or something else ? Please try using id or some other selector than using error class.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your selector on which you have set **.error** class.

Consider its **id** is **txtEmail** then you can use as below to remove **.error** class

```
$("#txtEmail").removeClass("error");
```

Comment: Its removing by this 
$("#b_first_name").validate(function(){
      $('#b_first_name').removeClass("error"); 
      });

but for all fields i have to write this code i have 50 to 60 fields is there any idea we can use by one or few line using element or something?

Comment: If validation rule is same then you can make common function to validate it just need to pass id.  better way is to use html5 no code required

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Add Class"/>
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="Remove Class"/>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#btn1").addClass("one");
    });

    $("#btn3").click(function(){
        $("#btn1").removeClass("one");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zWAEf/

Answer (score 0):

How is your form structure? suppose it is like this

```
<div id="testdiv>    // or any thing having id
    //your textboxes
 </div>
```

then you can use jquery as follows.

```
<script>
//create one function which add and removes error class
function CheckValidation()
{
    var alltxt = $("#testdiv input[type='text']");
    for(var i=0;i<alltxt.length;i++)
    {
       if(validation condition fail)
       {
          alltxt[i].className = "error";
       }
       else
       {
          alltxt[i].className = "";
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're using the jQuery [Validate](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/) plugin. If I'm correct then read on.

By default, the plugin will remove the `error` class when a valid input is entered and will assign a `valid` class.

So you don't have to set `success:function(){}`, unless if you want the plugin to behave differently on success.

It seems to me that you've set `success:function(){}` - which REMOVES the default behavior of removing the `error` class and assigning `valid` class - but you didn't assign a new function for on success. As a result, nothing happens on success.

So if you're fine with the default behavior on success, then just remove `success:function(){}` from your validate settings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah you are right i use jquery plugin
but when i remove success:function{} text box of one div remove error class automatically but the rest div cant
i have 4-5 div on same page and i validate them all in single function
so what is the problem there for not to remove error class of all div's?

Comment: Could you please show some of your code? From one of your comments on the other answers it looks like you're calling .validate() multiple times which is not the ideal way of using this plugin.

Answer (score -1):

```
success: function() { 
 $('Your-jquery-selector')removeClass("error");
}
```